# white screen shows up for php files in ubuntu 16, php 7, using nginx

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, ubuntu-16.04, php-7

I am trying to get php files working on my server. It has Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (Xenial) and PHP 7.0.14-2+deb.sury.org~xenial+1. I have been struggling to get this working and looking all over the internet for solutions which haven't worked so far. Here is my /etc/nginx/sites-available/default file:

```
server {
    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name myurl.com www.myurl.com

    ssl_certificate /some_file_path/...;
    ssl_certificate_key /some_file_path/...;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /some_file_path/...;

    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
    #       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #       # With php7.0-cgi alone:
    #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #       # With php7.0-fpm:
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #       deny all;
    #}
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myurl.com www.myurl.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#       listen 80;
#       listen [::]:80;
#
#       server_name example.com;
#
#       root /var/www/example.com;
#       index index.html;
#
#       location / {
#               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#       }
```

I'm thinking there is probably something wrong with this file. php7.0-fpm does exist in /var/run/php/, but it also exist in /run/php, and I have tried both /var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock and /run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock on the line that says `fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;` but that doesn't work either. I have run `nginx -t` followed by `sudo service nginx restart` after every change to see if it would work, but it did not.

Regular html files work, but php files do not work. I did try for a while to install php5 to see if I could get that working instead of php7 (which it installed by default because I am using ubuntu 16), but there seemed to be know php5-fpm.sock file when I did that (and I noticed when I tried that, that

```
`ls /etc/php/5.6` showed `apache2    cli    mods-available`
```

but no `fpm` directory

where as
     `ls /etc/php/7.0` showed `apache2    cli    fpm     mods-avaiable`

Now, I would actually prefer to get php 7 working, but php 5 would be a last resort, but as I have shown above, I was at a dead end at geting php5 working, because there was no php5-fpm.sock file to point to from nginx config file, and it seemed that php5-fpm seemed to be missing anyway. I think this is because the instructions I found of how to install php5 on ubuntu 16 were for apache (but I am not sure), and had me adding a repository for that. But I am using nginx. The repository that I talking about is: ppa:ondrej/php. If I can't get php7 working is there repository for php5-fpm with nginx and NOT apache?

Note: I just tried installing php7.1-fpm and updated the config file and restarted nginx, and I am still getting a white screen on php pages.

Any help on this would be very much appreciated.

Thankyou very much.

Comment: So is Server Fault new?, because how come I have seen tons of questions on stackoverflow about nginx configurations and they were never closed as off-topic?, and this did involve programming tools, because I was trying to get PHP to work, and I am a programmer, not a network administrator, but sometimes I still have to do things like configure nginx as part of my programming, as probably many others do.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer. I had to add this line: `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;` to my `location php block`.

But using `include fastcgi.conf;` in the `location php block` was the more permanent solution.

I will refer to this link for anyone else who has this problem: 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/website-displaying-blank-page-after-upgrading-ubuntu-server

The cause of this nginx php 7 problem in ubuntu 16 is according to ryanmortier "Prior to the update, /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params had a SCRIPT_FILENAME parameter.

However, the update removed that line and killed a lot of php-fpm sites." (this quote is taken from the link posted in this answer).